# Port numbers not hiding in nginx reverse proxy (next js server)

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, devops, next.js

I am trying to deploy a next-js app by create-next-app, I have a custom express server like this -

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const nextApp = next({ dev })
const handle = nextApp.getRequestHandler()

const fs = require('fs')

nextApp.prepare()
.then(() => {
    const server = express ()


    let port = 3000;

    let options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('some key..', 'utf-8'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('some cert..', 'utf-8'),
    };


    server.get(
        ...
    )


    let app = https.createServer(options, server)
    .listen((port), function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + port);
    });

})
.catch((ex) => {
    console.error(ex.stack)
    process.exit(1)
})
```

I want to deploy this as the website when someone types the URL subdomain.maindomain.com so I saved two nginx configuration files like this -

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default** AND **/etc/nginx/sites-available/subdomain.maindomain.com**

the default file contains this

```
server {

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name maindomain.com www.maindomain.com;

    location / {
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/maindomain.com/fullchain.pem;$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/maindomain.com/privkey.pe$
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

and the subdomain.maindomain.com file looks like this

```
server {
if ($host = www.subdomain.maindomain.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


if ($host = subdomain.maindomain.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/subdomain.maindomain.com/somecodefolder/;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name subdomain.maindomain.com www.subdomain.maindomain.com;


    location / {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

}

if I'm typing https://subdomain.maindomain.com:3000, everything works fine, I see my website running. But when I type https://subdomain.maindomain.com (without the port number) it shows nothing. How can I get the content I want when I type just the url without the port number. I have tried many combinations, but could'nt do. someone please help i've been trying since 2 days.

Comment: Did you try to open port 443 on your host ? What's the result of `sudo netstat -anp | grep listen -i`

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa this is what I get

https://imgur.com/a/00SUaAb

Comment: I opened it in the firewall @DimitriKopriwa

Comment: You are trying to access through `https://` so you expect nginx to listen on port `443` as you configured with `listen 443`. It seems that your nginx is not listening on that port.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to dev-ops, can you please tell me how to enable nginx to listen on port 443?

Comment: You did when you configured `listen 443 ssl;` , why is the port not listening I can't tell you, did you run the command as sudo and on the right host ?

Comment: Yes, I am positive about that, I have run this command - 
sudo yarn run start
which does this - set NODE_ENV=production && node server.js

server.js has code as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Try to see nginx access/errror log for the vhost that have `server_name maindomain.com www.maindomain.com;`

Comment: And when I ran sudo ufw status, I got this -

Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
8000                       ALLOW       Anywhere

Comment: 3000                       ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Comment: Then it seems that port 443 is open, try to verify it with curl `curl -vv -L -H 'Host: maindomain.com ' https://localhost` and `telnet localhost 443`

Comment: hey I tried that, after doing that when i go to url https://subdomain.maindomain.com, I get 
502 Bad Gateway
---------------------------
nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa, do you want me to paste the stuff I got when I did curl?

Comment: When i go to https://subdomain.maindomain.com:3000, I get what I desired

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa

Comment: 502 bad gateway means that the the backend service cannot be proxied by nginx. Did you set the Host header correctly? That's the way to let nginx know you are targetting a particular vhost, it's what your browser does when you access a website

Answer (score 4):

Try with other applications in order to validate if something is wrong in your application.

The nginx configuration to use domain instead ports are not complex.

## Steps

- npm install
- node main_domain.js
- node subdomain.js
- Check if webs are working:

[image: localhost]

- Add the following lines to your /etc/hosts. This will help us to use domains without the need to pay for a domain in godaddy, namecheap, etc.

```
127.0.0.1 maindomain.com
127.0.0.1 subdomain.maindomain.com
```

- Create a file in /etc/nginx/conf.d called **maindomain.com.conf** or whatever you want but with .conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name maindomain.com;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    }
}
```

- Create a file in /etc/nginx/conf.d called **conf.d/subdomain.maindomain.com.conf** or whatever you want but with .conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.maindomain.com;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
    }
}
```

- Restart the nginx

```
service nginx restart
```

- And now, you could use a domain instead ip:port

[image: domains]

Answer (score 2):

Try to change from

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
```

Into

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
```

Comment: Updated my comment

Comment: I changed it, no luck