# How do I deploy a Next.js app to an addon domain on cPanel, which listens to port 3000 without affecting my other domains?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, next.js, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a website running on my main domain added in cPanel listening to the main "80" port and can be opened without adding the port to the URL. for example: "http://mywebsite.com".

Now I want to add another website on a new addon domain. But this website is a Next.js app running on port 3000.

- I used SSH to successfully build and start the next.js app.
- The next.js app opens perfectly on the newly added addon domain with the port 3000. For example "http://new-website.com:3000"

**- If I change the port from 3000 to 80 when starting the next.js app, I can open it without adding the port, but the problem is, that my other domain will now also open the next.js app.**

My server Information:

- Virtual instance running on google cloud.
- CentOS 7
- Apache Web server (I can turn off Apache and run NGINX if needed)
- cPanel installed

I can of course just create another virtual instance and add my new website there but I don't want to pay double when my current instance is capable of running multiple websites on different domains.

Everything is working perfectly with my both websites and the only problem is I cannot have my both websites work currently without having to add port number to my next.js app.

**How do I open my new next.js app without adding the port in a way that my other static website won't be affected and show it's content like before?**

Tried:

- I used NGINX reverse proxy, but the same thing happens.
- Changing next.js port from 3000 to 80
- Exporting the next.js app and uploading it as static using "npx next export" but website not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is possible to do this with Nginx reverse proxy and setting different ports and assigning them to different domains!

Got the answer from this Stackoverflow question:

[Port numbers not hiding in nginx reverse proxy (next js server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54062360/port-numbers-not-hiding-in-nginx-reverse-proxy-next-js-server)

[The link to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54095059/2005195)

In my case I changed server name from subdomain to my other website and removed the location since my other website is static and does not need port.

```
 server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  my-website-2.com;
    root         "Website_directory";
   }
```